# Deleting an SMS or changing its status from unread

Tags: android

I know that in newer android api levels its not possible to abort received sms broadcast or delete received or sent sms.Even when we send sms from SmsManager it is saved in inbox.
My first question is.Is there any way to delete sms in android 6.0 or atleast change received sms status to already read.
Second is there anyway to send sms silently which does not save itself in inbox.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to delete sms in android 6.0 or atleast change received sms status to already read.

No. Its not possible unles you make your app default SMS. Starting from Andriod Kitkat only SMS default app has capability to Write data to the provider

> Second is there anyway to send sms silently which does not save itself in inbox.

You can send Binary SMS which won't be visible in the Inbox/Sent box